# Customize Django Admin Advice

Tags: python, django

I have a series of filters I need to run and then I want the ability to loop though the results. I'm thinking of starting with a form where I can select the filter options. I want a next/previous buttons when I'm looping.

How would I implement this? I'm just looking for high level advice and sample code if available.

I know I can set index_template in AdminSite to create the first page. I know there is the SimpleListFilter but I don't think I can use it since I want multiple filters that need to be configured. Also I don't want to have to select all the models to loop though them. I plan on writing a custom add/change view.

I'm not sure how to go from the selected filter options to looping though each of the selected models. I'm not sure if I can pass and store a query set for when I loop though each model. Some of the options I've thought about is storing the filter parameters in the url and the current model number. Another thing I thought about is storing the results in database and recalling it.

**Update**
Someone thought this was too broad so I'll be a little more specific.  I think the best solution will be to inherit from AdminSite and overwrite index_template to be a form that will contain the filters.  How would I link the form submit to a view that will loop though the items?  I assume I'll need to add a custom view to the admin but I'm not sure how to pass the data to the view.

Comment: I've voted to close the question as too broad, not to be a jerk, but because it'd be more productive if you gave some of the things you want to do a try, and then asked questions on here when you ran into problems or discovered more specific architectural concepts that you wanted to understand well. I used to ask super broad questions when I started here as well, and they never ended up with helpful answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite a broad question but I'll give it a shot.

There are a few ways you can achieve this:

Setting up a model with filter queries as variables.

models:

```
class Filter(models.Model):
    Filter_Query = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

views:

```
from app_name.models import Filter, Some_Model

def filter(request, pk):
  template = loader.get_template("app_name/filter_search.html")
  filter_1 = Filter.objects.get(id=pk)  
  some_model = Some_Model.objects.all() 
  filter_1_search =  model_name.filter(some_option=filter_1)  
  context = RequestContext(request, {'filter_1_search': filter_1_search})
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

Then in a separate page, you can load the results like so.

```
{$("#some_div").load(filter/1)
```

or even easier you can you can just use AJAX to send whatever filter query you want.

views:

```
from app_name.models import Some_Model

def filter_query(request):
  filter_1 = request.GET.get('filter_query', '')# Receives from AJAX
  some_model = Some_Model.objects.all() 
  filter_1_search =  model_name.filter(some_option=filter_1)  
  jsonDump = json.dumps(str(filter_1_search))
     return HttpResponse(jsonDump, content_type='application/json')
```

javascript:

```
var data_JSON_Request = {'filter_query': filter_search1, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': "{{csrf_token}}"};//JSON package.

function ajax_call(data_JSON_Request){
  $(function jQuery_AJAX(){
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: '/filter_query/',
      data: data_JSON_Request,
      datatype: "json",
      success: function(data) {$("#sove_div").load(data);
            open_model_menu();
      },//success
      error: function() {alert("failed...");}
    });//.ajax
  });//jQuery_AJAX
};//ajax_call
```

Comment: I ended up creating models for my different filters and using a modelForm.  Then I inherited from AdminSite and overwrote the <index> method.  I added views to the custom admin to handle the ajax calls from the index template.